# useMemo with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-usememo

I'm new with Redux, and I'd like to improve performances of my web app as much as possible.

I have a state in redux, that I store in a variable to display it later.

Here is the code :

```
const metricsState = useSelector((state: MetricsStateObject) => state.MetricsState);
const myMetrics = metricsState.myMetrics;
```

I saw that [useMemo](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usememo.asp) improve performance by not re-render if the data did not mutate.

So I'm wondering if `const myMetrics = useMemo(() => metricsState.myMetrics, [metricsState.myMetrics]);` is a good practice, or totaly useless ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useMemo` is for high cost computation, you dont want to run each render. Like

```
const something = useMemo(()=> megaBigArray.reduce((acc,i)=>acc*i,0), [megaBigArray])
```

or something like that. You only calculate that variable, if `megaBigArray`change.

In your case, that code will be run every render anyways, but `useSelector` should trigger render only, when part of store you are selecting change. So you should be good without it.

Comment: I understand better now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Let me talk about the conclusion first, it's totally  useless.

why?
because `metricsState.myMetrics` is just a `value-taking` process and does not involve expensive calculations.

but `useMemo` itself consumes a certain amount of calculation.

so I think that belongs to premature optimization

Comment: Very clear. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think @Wraithys answer is not correct here. I'm pretty sure, React will not compute the component with the useSelector if the state of the selector didn't change **and the selector also didn't change.** This means that you must memoize the selector too, otherwise React and Redux will not be able to optimize the rendering. I think you may have to also memoize the component using React.memo() for it to work fully. Also, it may be best to always state your selectors in a file so you don't have to memoize them, since they are constant.

Comment: you think or you are sure ?

Comment: @AhmedSbai I am sure, it can be verified if you have a large collection of components where all are using the useSelector hook for their own distinct state, then after memoizing their unique selector, they won't update. You can check by updating only the state of one object and tracking the updates using the React devtools. I had this problem in my own project where I drasticaly increased the performance by memoizing a curried selector for each objects state using its id.
This page https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors explains it fully.